# How to use front camera

Tags: android

I am trying to use the front camera, however the back camera is appearing instead. What's the problem?

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if (!previewing) 
   {
   camera = Camera.open();
   if (camera != null) 
   {
   try 
   {
       camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
       camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceholder);
       Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
       p.set("camera_id",2);
       camera.setParameters(p);
       camera.startPreview();
       previewing = true;
     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since API level 9 there is a method `Camera.open(int)` where you can give the number of the desired camera as parameter

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code below to get the front facing camera

```
private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return cam;
}
```